# DOCKER CONTAINER (connect EHOSTUNREACH 172.21.0.2:3306)

Tags: mysql, node.js, linux, docker-compose, docker-network

2 DOCKER CONTAINER CANT COMMUNICATE TOGETHER
node:events:491
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

Error: connect EHOSTUNREACH 172.21.0.2:3306
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1494:16)
Emitted 'error' event on Connection instance at:
at Connection._notifyError (/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:250:12)
at Connection._handleFatalError (/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:181:10)
at Connection._handleNetworkError (/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:194:10)
at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
errno: -113,
code: 'EHOSTUNREACH',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '172.21.0.2',
port: 3306,
fatal: true
}

Node.js v18.16.0

Hello Guys,
Im New in Docker and my problem is that my 2 Container can´t communicate together.
I created 2 Network and both are in, but my 1 Container (NODEJS) cant reach the 2 Container (MYSQL). Both are in my LINUX VPS SERVER ON IONOS (UBUNTU 22.04)

The funny part is that in my local machine everything works fine, they can communicate together.
MY DOCKER COMPOSE:

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  server:
    platform: linux/amd64
    container_name: server
    image: image-name
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - /secrets/private.env:/secrets/private.env
      - /secrets/private.key:/secrets/private.key
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    networks:
      - backend
      - frontend
  mysql:
    platform: linux/amd64
    image: mysql:8.0.33-oracle
    container_name: mysql
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "1200:3306"
    environment:
    # first password change it after success starting
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=<mypass>
    volumes:
      - test:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - backend
volumes:
  test:
    name: test
networks:
  backend:
    name: backend
  frontend:
    name: frontend

MY DOCKER CONTAINER MYSQL WORKS FINE NO PROBLEMS!

BUT MY DOCKER CONTAINER NODEJS SHOWS ME:
node:events:491
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect EHOSTUNREACH 172.21.0.2:3306
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1494:16)
Emitted 'error' event on Connection instance at:
    at Connection._notifyError (/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:250:12)
    at Connection._handleFatalError (/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:181:10)
    at Connection._handleNetworkError (/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:194:10)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  errno: -113,
  code: 'EHOSTUNREACH',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '172.21.0.2',
  port: 3306,
  fatal: true
}
```

Node.js v18.16.0

DOCKER NETWORK INSPECT BACKEND :

```json
[
    {
        "Name": "backend",
        "Id": "a67adf8efbdfcffdbd00e63269561ac7c1b0f79fb3460666a7490e8aabb1c6d6",
        "Created": "2023-06-03T21:14:29.510664575Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.21.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.21.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "3c79839a537283bdeb0914f0ed84335d37b7c15ddd2dd6bc3330e7f4d178e571": {
                "Name": "server",
                "EndpointID": "d799f1344da8ab61d283f233e8049a936e885b5673d946153e998ef600e50dfb",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:15:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.21.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "92c2076d1a83c15c9953e643f138fa5c1e42383c6f74284a457d04cfeed5e2b8": {
                "Name": "mysql",
                "EndpointID": "3a26c7d0366200515d4f713c90008dfc9239a1907499890fdc6cb11196dd191b",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:15:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.21.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "backend",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "docker",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "2.3.3"
        }
    }
]
```

nodejs part:

```js
// imports packages
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const helmet = require( "helmet");
// limit the api request on the server
const rateLimit = require("express-rate-limit");
const limiter = rateLimit({
  windowMs: 1000, // Zeitfenster in Millisekunden (hier: 1 Sekunde)
  max: 3, // Maximale Anzahl von Anfragen pro Zeitfenster und pro IP-Adresse
  message: "Zu viele Anfragen von dieser IP, bitte versuche es später erneut.",
});
// INIT 
const app = express();
app.use(limiter)
app.use(helmet())
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
// set timeer for mysql connection 
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}

async function start(){
  console.log("start")

  const pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: mysql,
    port: process.env.PORT,
    user: process.env.DBUSER,
    password: process.env.PASS,
    database: process.env.DB,
  });
  
  await sleep(2000)

  pool.getConnection(async (err, connection) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error acquiring MySQL connection:', err);
      return;
    }
    console.log("connected");
  
    const server = app.listen(8000);
  
    server.on('close', ()=>{
      connection.release();
      pool.end(); 
    });
  })
}
start()
```

the funny part is if i start the both container with docker run --net=host ... it works ...

Additional Information:
my port are all open 8000,3306 on my linux VPS
i build it in my local machine so i saved my server image with docker save -o server.tar and in my linux machine: docker save -i server.tar ,

FAZIT: on my local machine it works fine, on my linux machine it works fine ONLY if i make docker run --net=host

Comment: Have you tried connecting to port `1200` for MySQL? See [Difference between `expose` and `ports` in Docker Compose](https://www.baeldung.com/ops/docker-compose-expose-vs-ports)

Comment: What is your environment config? We need to see all the connection details (minus private credentials).

Comment: i tried also 1200, my env config is:
host: process.env.HOST = mysql
port: process.env.PORT = 3306